# Date formatter memory leak

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, nsdateformatter

Hey, I've been wokring through my app and removing the memory leaks but the below one has me beaten, any help would be much appreciated.

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

claim.date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[data objectForKey:key]];
[dateFormatter release];
```

The date property is defined as:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *date
```

Thanks

Edit:

Forgot to mention where the memory leak occurred, its on line `claim.date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[data objectForKey:key]];`

Comment: Do you release date property in dealloc method?

Comment: @kovpas, thanks that was exactly the cause of it, I wasn't releasing the property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect one or both of the following:

1. The owner of `claim` never released it
2. The implementation of `claim` does not send the release message to `date` in its `dealloc` and/or does not `self.date = nil` in the `viewDidUnload`.